# How to properly run find | parallel with grep + escape characters?

Tags: regex, grep, gnu-parallel

I have approximately 1500 2GB files in a folder and would like to extract lines from them based on a regex. I tried:

```sh
find . -regex "filename pattern" -exec grep -P "pattern1\t|pattern2\t|pattern3\t|...|patternN\t" {} +
```

which works perfectly, but is pretty slow. I then read about running `grep` with GNU `parallel`, but couldn't figure out how to properly use it. Here's what I tried:

```sh
find . -regex "filename pattern" | parallel grep -P "pattern1\t|pattern2\t|pattern3\t|...|patternN\t" {}
```

along with a few variations of this command. However, I get in return:

```sh
/bin/bash: pattern1t: command not found
/bin/bash: pattern3t: command not found
/bin/bash: pattern2t: command not found
...
```

It seems the problem lies with the `\t` I use to ensure I match an entire string in a column of a TSV file. The `grep` command without parallel works perfectly with this regex.

How can I use escape characters in the `grep` regex with `parallel`?

Comment: `find ... -print0 | parallel -0 --quote grep -P '...'` should work

Comment: @MarkSetchell It works perfectly, thanks! I had dismissed the `--quote` option after reading that `Most people will never need this` in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Mark Setchell pointed out, I missed the "--quote" argument! This solution works:

```
find . -regex "filename pattern" -print0 | parallel -0 --quote grep -P "pattern1\t|pattern2\t|pattern3\t|...|patternN\t"
```